# case insensitive highlighting in php

Tags: php, search, highlight, case-insensitive

i'm using this function to highlight the results from mysql query:

```
 function highlightWords($string, $word)
 {

        $string = str_replace($word, "<span class='highlight'>".$word."</span>", $string);
    /*** return the highlighted string ***/
    return $string;

 }

 ....

  $cQuote =  highlightWords(htmlspecialchars($row['cQuotes']), $search_result);
```

the problem is, if i type in 'good', it will only show my search results with a lower-case 'g'ood and not 'Good'. how do i rectify this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `str_ireplace()` instead.

EDIT: Here is regexp version that keeps original case:

```
$string = preg_replace("/".preg_quote($word, "/")."/i", "<span class='highlight'>$0</span>", $string);
```

Comment: that works, but what it does is that it changes the capital 'G' to small 'g'. any other ideas?

Comment: You should use `preg_quote($word, '/')` instead of just `$word`.

Comment: @FrancisMV123 the match of the first argument

Comment: Thanks so much! Helped after an hour of headaches with Regex