# PHP Case-insensitive equivalent of strtr

Tags: php, arrays, case-insensitive, strtr

Where I could find a case-insensitive version of `strtr`?

`strtr` is overloaded, I am talking about the following one

```
string strtr ( string $str , array $replace_pairs )
```

Comment: @c69, read function's name one more time. It's `strtr`, not `strstr`.

Comment: @binaryLV damn php and its function names >_< they are not very reader friendly

Comment: @c69, it's not only PHP. C standard library also has awesome names for functions. Take a look at [string.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String.h#Functions) (`strcspn()`?!), for example ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str_ireplace`](http://php.net/str_ireplace):

```
str_ireplace(array_keys($replace_pairs), array_values($replace_pairs), $str);
```

Comment: works (almost) perfectly! The only minor issue is that uppercase characters are turned lowercase... But I can live with that, I guess.

Comment: `str_ireplace(array('A'), array('Z'), "ABcd")` returns `ZBcd`, it doesn't change the case of the input string.

Comment: str_ireplace(array('a'),array('z'), 'ABcd'); does ;)

Comment: obviously, it replaces by what you tell him to replace with ;) do `str_replace(array('a','A'),array('z','Z'), 'ABcd');` instead

Comment: Yes I know. However, I do not have the knowledge of the string I want to process. If I want to replace a whole set of words, I should generate all combination of lower/upper-case characters ?

Imagine with only 1 word of three letters: bob, boB, bOb, bOB, Bob, BoB, BOb, BOB.

The problem is that I've got n words of different length. Generating all the possible combinations just to preserve the case seems to be a big overhead.

Comment: And with non-western alphabets, I am not even how case should be handled.

Comment: OK: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750736/case-insensitive-highlighting-in-php seems to address this secondary issue. I still consider your answer valid anyway :)

Comment: Remember that it poses a problem when you replace all number for example, then you can't decipher it anymore. It replaces sequentually instead of at the same time, like strtr does do!

Comment: Note that `str_replace()`/`str_ireplace()` are functionally different to `strtr()` in how they perform replacements.  If you are using the former with user supplied values you may end up with a code-injection vulnerability.

Comment: Problem is that str_replace ans str_ireplace is 4 times slower then strtr

Comment: This is a nice answer as it uses the same format array as strtr  thanks to array_keys and array_values.   I mention it because I started to write a conversion function before I realised.