# PHP str_replace bug

Tags: php, string, str-replace

I'm running simple PHP code

```
$myVariable = 1;
$myVariable2 = str_replace(array(1, 2, 3), array('do 25 lat', 'od 26 do 35 lat', 'pow. 35 r.z.'), $myVariable);
echo $myVariable2;
```

And result is:

> do od 26 do pow. 35 r.z.5 lat5 lat

I checked on different PHP versions. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the output are you expecting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [str\_replace with array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715826/str-replace-with-array)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're falling victim to the *gotcha* specified in the documentation - look under "notes" on the [`str_replace` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

> Replacement order gotcha
>
> Because str_replace() replaces left to right, it might replace a previously inserted value when doing multiple replacements. See also the examples in this document.

Essentially what's happening is the sequential replacements, as you passed an array as the second parameter:

1. *1* is replaced with *do 25 lat*
2. In that string, *2* is replaced with *od 26 do 35 lat*, giving you *do od 26 do 35 lat5 lat*
3. In that string, *3* is replaced with pow. *35 r.z.* giving you the final result you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `str_replace` array pairs are applied one after the other.

Try `strtr`:

```
$myVariable = 1;
$replacePairs = array(
    1 => "do 25 lat",
    2 => "od 26 do 35 lat",
    3 => "pow. 35 r.z."
);
$myVariable2 = strtr($myVariable,$replacePairs);
echo $myVariable2;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, this is the normal behavior of `str_replace`. What happens is the function iterates through your `search` array and each time it finds an occurrence, it replaces it with relevant `replace`.

Thus:

```
(search and match 1) 1 -> "do 25 lat"
(search and match 2) "do 25 lat" -> "do od 26 do 35 lat5 lat"
(search and match 3) "do od 26 do 35 lat5 lat" -> "do od 26 do pow. 35 r.z.5 lat5 lat"
```