# Check if string has substring and remove it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I run the following:

**Note:** `usp-custom-8` is a custom field with a string like **"United States"** or **"china"** etc

Sometimes the nations have an extra string at the beginning like: **"[Image] United States"** and I need to remove **["Image"]** and leave the country name only. With the following I was trying to check if the `custom field` has a particular `string` and if so, change it and `update the field`. But it isn't working and also, this won't be a general code which in one shot will remove all **["Image"]** but I'd have to manually run it for each country.

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
  $title = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-8');
  if (preg_match('/\b[Image] United States\b/', $title)) {
   update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-custom-8', 'United States' );
  }
endwhile; endif;
```

Comment: `substr`, `strpos`?

Comment: @Script47 but it needs to match exactly that, otherwise i search for "war" and it'll find it in "Award"

Comment: did you try strchr function

Comment: @NigHamza but I tried strpos and that looks for any string within a word and that's not ideal

Comment: Why are you saving `[image]` this thing in one meta? Why can't you use different meta fields with the same post id?

Comment: @KrishnadasPC it's an import from CSV. I want to remove ["Image"]

Comment: Am not sure whether this is what you want. If it has been from a csv file, can you try opening it in a plain text editor and replace `[Image]` with empty string then upload it to WordPress

Comment: @KrishnadasPC thanks, another OP provided a working answer.

Comment: That `str_replace` and this will do the same thing. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go for the simplest option of just replacing `[Image]` with a blank using `str_replace()`...

```
if (have_posts()) : 
    while (have_posts()) : 
        the_post();
        $title = usp_get_meta(false, 'usp-custom-8');
        update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'usp-custom-8',
            str_replace('[Image]', '', $title ));
    endwhile; 
endif;
```

Comment: Problem is that you could come up with 100's of alternatives, unless you come up with a fixed algorithm - you may end up having to have a translation array.  One thing you can do is pass `str_replace()` an array of things you want to replace and what you want to replace it with - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715826/str-replace-with-array