# PHP replace in foreach loop replace only last item from array list

Tags: php, str-replace

my problem is with replacing keywords in a context to links

```html
<?php
$keywords = file("Keywords.txt"); 
shuffle($keywords);

$FullContent = "Owning a home sure is great but it also comes with plenty of responsibilities. There are times when no matter how diligent you've been, a home repair is necessary. On occasions like this, a lot of homeowners like to tackle the repairs on their own. Still there are some fixes you shouldn't take on yourself, since just a tiny mistake can end up costing you a real fortune. With this in mind, we have come up with 5 home repairs you should always leave to professionals.
Plumbing

A routine running toilet may be an easy fix, but when facing most of the other plumbing issues, turning to professionals is a much better option. Even if you have some plumbing experience and can identify the problem, tackling it yourself is never recommended. This is simply due to the fact that professional plumbers have all the necessary tools and know exactly what to do in case something goes wrong. On the other hand, if more unexpected issues arrive while you're doing a repair, it can all turn into a real river of trouble.
Roof Issues

Improper flashing, missing shingles, and damage caused by falling debris or harsh weather are just some of the roof issues you might experience. No matter which of them you face, chances are you'll be tempted to bring your ladders and start the repair on your own. Still, improper repairs can lead to some other issues such as mold, rot, and mildew. Not to mention that there's always danger of you falling down and getting injured. And this can all be avoided if you just call in local roof specialists and stay on the ground.
Ceiling

Many people believe that a simple patch may be enough to deal with cracks and holes in their ceiling but this never turns out to be a good idea. Just take a look at it this way - patching a crack or a hole in your ceiling won't do more help than applying a band aid to a real gunshot wound would. The cause of any ceiling issue in your home needs to be tracked down so that you can find the best solution for it. This is always better left to professionals who have seen plenty of issues like this and know exactly what to look for. Not only this, but they will also be able to advise you on the best and least expensive way for dealing with it.
Electrical Issues

There's no need to say that most electrical issues one can experience should never be handled by amateur electricians. No matter if it's a glitch with electrical supply, overloaded circuit, exposed or corroded electrical wires, contacting your local electrician is always a much safer option. Just the risk of electrocution is a reason enough not to try and do some repairing on your own. Dire situations call for an electrician that deals with those sort of things on a daily basis, such as an emergency electrician from Staywired Electrical, for example.
Gas appliances

A standard home has a couple of appliances that run on gas. Your oven, water heater, and clothes dryer are a few. If anything was to go wrong with these appliances or you simply want to have them replaced, turning to the pros is always recommended. This is the case because even if you manage to repair it yourself, there are always chances of you not hooking it up properly once the repair is made, and put yourself and your family at risk of carbon monoxide poisoning.

There are some easy home repairs that DIY enthusiasts can tackle but these 5 are none of them. No matter which of the issues described above you face, make sure you have professionals deal with it for you, even if means spending a buck or two";

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
 $FullContent = str_replace($keyword, " <a href='https://www.google.com/search?num=100&source=hp&q=".$keyword."'>$keyword</a> ",$FullContent);
}
  
echo $FullContent;
```

problem is that only replace the last keyword from the list

Keywords.txt contain:

```
home
electrical
water
gas
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [str\_replace with array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715826/str-replace-with-array)

Comment: it's not a dublicate, i've read all posts about this topic, no one related to mine

Comment: Can you add an example of what `$FullContent` may contain and an example of what `$keywords` would contain with the output you get.

Comment: @SergheiPogor the question may not be - but the solution applies. You're overwriting the string each time in the loop. Just strstr with an array and your problem is solved, and with less overheads

Comment: $FullContent is content of article(text >2000 words), $keywords - a list of keywords loaded from a txt file that need to be found(if exist) in $FullContent and replaced with a specific link

Comment: @SergheiPogor if you make an effort to provide a functioning example of the problem, someone _may_ take the time to point out what's wrong with the code in the question. "Here is code. Guess problem" is not a fun game.

Comment: @AD7 Depends on how many beers you've had…

Comment: Why do you `shuffle($keywords)`…?

Comment: I use shuffle because for some Fullcontent I have large number or keywords and I want to be repalced random. For example: electric and electric supply, I want, in some Fullcontent to replace only "electric", in other only "electric supply" randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `file`
>
> **Note**
> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` is used.
>
> http://php.net/file

Your keywords aren't matching because they contain a `\n`. Add the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag.

Answer (score 1):

As Deceze points out your problem is that you are trying to match a keyword with a trailing newline.

Personally I would want to only substitute words (by taking word boundaries into account).  Also pattern detection likely needs to be case insensitive with your swaps not changing existing case.

```
<?php    

/*
Contents of things.txt:
cat
dog
mink
cow
*/

$keywords = file('/tmp/things.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$text = "
A cow is a nice animal.  A bobcat is a kind of wild Cat.
";

foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $text = 
    preg_replace(
        "#\b($keyword)\b#i",
        "<a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=$keyword'>$1</a>",
        $text
    );
}

echo $text;
```

Output:

```
A <a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=cow'>cow</a> is a nice animal.  A bobcat is a kind of wild <a href='https://www.google.com/search?q=cat'>Cat</a>.
```

Comment: You can add a fourth argument of 1 to preg_replace to limit replacements to one substitution per time.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this with str_replace is:

```
$arr_src = [];
$arr_rpl = [];
foreach($keywords as $keyword) {
    $arr_src[] = $keyword;
    $arr_rpl[] = "<a href='https://www.google.com/search?num=100&source=hp&q=3".$keyword."'>"
}
$FullContent = str_replace($arr_src, $arr_rpl, $FullContent)
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit subjective? Some may say preg_replace is the best

Comment: thanks deceze, with FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES all work fine