# Case insensitive highlighting with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Trying to fix case-insensitive keyword search results highlighting. Here is the broken code:

```
replaceNoCase(text, keyword, '<font style="background-color:yellow;">#keyword#</font>', 'all')
```

The problem of course is that the case of the keyword in the text gets changed to whatever the user entered.

Here is a solution in PHP [case insensitive highlighting in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2750736/case-insensitive-highlighting-in-php) but I don't know of a way to access the matched value in the searched text when using ColdFusion's REReplaceNoCase function. Any ideas for how to solve this?

Comment: 1.) Consider using a `<span class="highlight">` approach instead. 2) Do you want to upper case or lower case the `keyword`?

Comment: Where will the highlighted content be viewed?  Online only?  If so, you may have better luck using a javascript library to highlight the words in the element before you display it.  This is what I use. http://bartaz.github.io/sandbox.js/jquery.highlight.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more like this:

```
highlightedText = reReplaceNoCase(text, "(#keyword#)", '<span class="highlight">\1</span>', "ALL");
```

Docs: [REReplaceNoCase()](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REReplaceNoCase)

I go through CFML's regex system reasonably thoroughly - from the ground up - on my blog: ["Regular expressions in CFML" link summary](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2015/01/regular-expressions-in-cfml-link-summary.html)

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, reReplace will simply replace your text with whatever text the user entered (case and all). Here's what I would do instead:

1. Convert the text to a list using pipes as delimiters (because
   pipes are rarely used in normal text)
2. Loop through each item on the list
3. Perform a case insensitive search on the list item
4. If the list item is a match, create a new variable which prepends
   the current item with an opening span tag and appends it with a
   closing span tag (this keeps the current case of the text rather
   than replacing it with the search text)
5. Save the new variable in the current list position
6. When the loop is complete, replace the pipes with spaces

Here's a quick and dirty gist.  Try it out and see if it works for you:
https://gist.github.com/kriskorsmo/6d02e06bc4a8483b3341

And here's a live demo of it on my blog: 
kriskorsmo.com/examples/highlighting.cfm

I created a simple "highlight" function in there for you too. It takes two arguments - keyword and originalText - and returns the original text with the keywords highlighted.

******EVEN BETTER******
There's a UDF at CFLib.org - http://www.cflib.org/udf/Highlight

Comment: If you are going to create a list, `chr(30)` would be a better separator than a pipe.  It never gets used.

Comment: I see on http://www.joecolantonio.com/2011/07/26/qtp-ascii-chr-code-chart/ that `chr(30)` is `Record Separator`. It sounds a lot better than commas, pipes and tildes that I have been using all these years

Answer (score 0):

**ColdFusion**

```
replaceNoCase(text, keyword, '<span style="highlight">#keyword#</span>', 'all')
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight {
    background-color:yellow;
    text-transform: capitalize;
    }
```

The capitalize will make the first letter caps.

You may want to

```
replaceNoCase(text, keyword, '<span style="highlight">#lcase(keyword)#</span>', 'all')
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was unclear...the keyword needs to keep the capitalization it has in the original text when it get highlighted. Currently, whatever capitalization the user enters, gets substituted for the original text.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this? But it does involve some boolean logic.

Edit: Doesn't work.

```
<cfset keyword = "batman">
<cfset text = "SOMETHING BATMAN SOMETHING.">
<cfoutput>
    #(FindNoCase(keyword, text))? ReplaceNoCase(text, keyword, '<font style="background-color:yellow;">' & Mid(text, FindNoCase(keyword, text), Len(keyword)) & '</font>', 'all') : text#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Did you try it yourself when the keyword appears more than once?

Comment: Hmm, right I should've probably used a replace method. :(